# pandas convert datatime column to timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am beginner in pandas

I have dataframe first column is datatime like "19-Sep-2016 10:30:00" and many records like it.

I am trying to convert this column to timestamp and write it to another dataframe , i am trying to do it with one step.

I am trying to write in python 3.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from time import strptime

xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df = xl.parse(sheetname=0)
our_df['DateTime'] = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(df['Date Time'], "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")))
```

but I have error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I am trying to google it but I take long time without benefits.

Now, how can I do it the right way?

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: time.strptime function will take each vale in string format. but you are providing a complete column

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime':['19-Sep-2016 10:30:00','19-Sep-2016 10:30:00']})
print (df)
               DateTime
0  19-Sep-2016 10:30:00
1  19-Sep-2016 10:30:00

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
print (df)
             DateTime
0 2016-09-19 10:30:00
1 2016-09-19 10:30:00
```

If want to specify format:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
print (df)
             DateTime
0 2016-09-19 10:30:00
1 2016-09-19 10:30:00
```

And for `times` add [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.time
print (df)
   DateTime
0  10:30:00
1  10:30:00
```

Then is possible use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) - data are aligned by index values, if length is different get `NaT`s as last values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col':[5, 4, 0, 7]})
print (df1)
   Col
0    5
1    4
2    0

df1 = df1.join(pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']))
print (df1)
   Col            DateTime
0    5 2016-09-19 10:30:00
1    4 2016-09-19 10:30:00
2    0                 NaT
3    7                 NaT
```

```
df1['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
print (df1)
   Col            DateTime
0    5 2016-09-19 10:30:00
1    4 2016-09-19 10:30:00
2    0                 NaT
3    7                 NaT
```

---

```
df1 = df1.join(pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.time)
print (df1)
   Col  DateTime
0    5  10:30:00
1    4  10:30:00
2    0       NaN
3    7       NaN
```

```
df1['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.time
print (df1)
   Col  DateTime
0    5  10:30:00
1    4  10:30:00
2    0       NaN
3    7       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert it to a `long` timestamp:

```py
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['TimeStamp'] = df.DateTime.astype('int64') // 10**9
```

That will give you the timestamp in milliseconds.