# Parse datetime with pandas

Tags: pandas

Error while parsing datetime with pandas

I have tried a simple input with custom format as
Year-Month-DayTHour_Minute_Second

```
pd.to_datetime('2019-01-05T05_44_07', format='%Y-%b-%dT%H_%M_%S', utc=True)
```

End I am getting this error

> ValueError: time data '2019-01-05T05_44_07' does not match format
>   '%Y-%b-%dT%H_%M_%S' (match)

Comment: Your format string is incorrect for the Month: `format='%Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%S'`, see [python strftime](http://strftime.org/)

Comment: Thanks is works. I build the incorrect format based on posts like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751651/pandas-convert-datatime-column-to-timestamp

Comment: `%b'` is used for month abbreviation like `'Jan'` , `'Feb'` etc..

Comment: Nice to know. Thanks again.